# How to change div background depending on which img element is hovered over using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I've only recently started studying Javascript and I need help changing the div background to one of three images when the img is hovered over. I want to link all three images to one function that will change the div background to the image that is hovered over. Using JS I have only been able to get it to work on one image so how can a get the function to work on all three images depending on which img is hovered over?

```
<div id = "image">
    Hover over an image below to display here.
</div>

<img class = "preview" alt = "" src = "bacon.jpg" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">

<img class = "preview" alt = "" src = "bacon2.JPG" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">

<img class = "preview" src = "bacon3.jpg" alt = "" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">
```

Javascrpit

```
function upDate(previewPic){
    document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = "url('bacon.jpg')";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function upDate(previewPic){
    document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = `url('${previewPic.src}')`;
 }
```

Comment: Dont; forget to remove the unDo() to avoid errors. Or add code: function unDo( ){
        document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = 'unset';
    }

Comment: Thanks for the help it worked! When I typed it in it didn't work because I used "url('${previewPic.src}')" and realized that it was because of the backticks used around the outside of the code. Why is it essential to use backticks over the inverted commas? Also, how can I add the alt text to also appear?